# OLED screen not working when I change code on Arduino from 128x32 to 128x64

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, oled

I am having an issue with my new OLED screen (128x64).
I was using the SSD1306 driver to run an OLED 128x32 screen without any issues with the Arduino. Then I swapped out the screen with a bigger 128x64 (different manufacturer) and I changed the code for the HEIGHT from 32 to 64 and it is not recognized. Surprisingly, leaving the HEIGHT at 32 turns the screen on. Changing the sddress also didn't work. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Here is the code:

```
//OLED SCREEN 
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <splash.h>
#include <U8glib.h>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 //OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

#define OLED_RESET     4 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3C ///< See datasheet for Address; 0x3D for 128x64, 0x3C for 128x32
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
```

---

Buffer was too large for the 128X64 so I made my code a bit more efficient.

Comment: OK. But you are using Arduino modules on Arduino so perhaps Arduino Stackexchange would have more people knowing about this. We don't know what display you bought, and whether it is compatible with the driver you have.

Comment: Do you have enough memory to allocate the display buffer?

Comment: I do have enough memory. The screen fires up when I change the height to 32.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet, specifications, or at least a reference for the screen?

Comment: It was a memory issue. The buffer was too large.

Comment: Just to spell out the logic here, making the height 64 from 32 almost doubles the amount of memory allocated in this malloc statement: 
  if ((!buffer) && !(buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(WIDTH * ((HEIGHT + 7) / 8))))
    return false;  So the failure when HEIGHT is doubled is a strong clue that memory is the issue.

Comment: Change your screen address to 0x3D